# Kafka State Store low level API persist into ROCKDB ? if yes then is there any documentation for configuration for ROCK DB

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

Kafka State Store low level API  persist into ROCKDB ? if yes then is there any documentation for configuration for ROCK DB . If no then what is using for low level API 
Stores.create().withKeys().withValues().persistent().build();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use provide your custom RocksDB configs by implementing `RocksDBConfigSetter` interface and add you implementation class to `StreamsConifg`:

```
streamsConfig.put(StreamsConfig.ROCKSDB_CONFIG_SETTER_CLASS_CONFIG, CustomRocksDBConfig.class);
```

See: http://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide.html#non-streams-configuration-parameters